Error building Boost dynamic libraries on Windows with MSVC
I recently got a Windows laptop after having Macs for 13 years. I would love to just use WSL (I already built it on WSL just fine) but I need something that specifically runs on Windows and must be built by MSVC so here I am. I have been attempting to build Boost's dynamic libraries on Windows but I keep getting this error. I am attempting to build Boost 1.86.
...failed updating 2 targets...
   msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.3\debug\x86_32\python-3.8\threading-multi\boost_python38-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_87.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.3\debug\x86_32\python-3.8\threading-multi\boost_python38-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_87.lib bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.3\debug\x86_32\python-3.8\threading-multi\boost_python38-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_87.pdb
   msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.3\release\x86_32\python-3.8\threading-multi\boost_python38-vc143-mt-x32-1_87.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-14.3\release\x86_32\python-3.8\threading-multi\boost_python38-vc143-mt-x32-1_87.lib

My environment:
Windows 10
MS Visual Studio 2022 - 19.36.32537
Python 3.8.8
All commands run in an "Administrator Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022":
git clone https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
cd boost
git submodule update --init --recursive
boostrap msvc

My first try was just to install the entire library
b2 install --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" --build-type=complete fails with the error above
When that didn't work, I tried splitting up the builds into static/dynamic:
b2 install --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost"` builds just fine
b2 install --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" link=shared` fails with the error 

above
I have also tried building it with a mixture of the following flags:
toolset=msvc
threading=multi

EDIT:
I tried building it a few other ways, and the portion of the build that fails is
b2 install --prefix="C:\Program Files\Boost" threading=multi link=shared address-model=32

